# Getting ^D at the end of string in c

Tags: c, variable-assignment

So I have a homework assignment to do for Friday and I am having some trouble figuring out why this is happening.  Here is the code:

```
while(curVal < length)
{
     code[word][wordVal] = input[curVal];
     if(input[curVal + 1] == 32) //Is the current char in the input a space
     {
          word++;
          curVal++;
          wordVal = -1;
     }
     curVal++;
     wordVal++;
}
```

After this I print it out in a ncurses window.  For the input "Lucas is great" the output is:

```
     Lucas^D
     is
     great
```

The problem I am having is instead of printing "Lucas" it prints "Lucas^D".  If anyone understand what my code is doing and can hep me fix it I would really appreciate it.

Comment: before `word++;` you need to add `code[word][wordVal+1] = 0;`

Comment: Unrelated:  If you want to compare some character to a space character, just do it directly.  `' '` is a space character, just like `'A'` is the letter A character, so `if( input[curVal + 1] == ' ')`.

Answer (score 2):

A string in C consists of an array of characters with a NUL character at the end. The NUL character can be written as `'\0'`. If you forget to put the NUL character at the end of your string, then all sorts of bad things can happen, including printing garbage characters and/or crashing your program.

So you have two choices. You can fill the whole array with NUL characters before you start

```
memset( code, '\0', sizeof(code) );
```

Or you can insert the NUL character when you find the end of the string.

```
 if(input[curVal + 1] == ' ') //Is the current char in the input a space
 {
      code[word][wordval] = '\0';
      word++;
```

Answer (score 1):

Code does not terminate the char array properly with a `'\0'` to make the array a string.  Thus causes subsequent printing to be amiss - likely undefined behavior.

The terminating null character `'\0'` should be added after *each* `code[word][wordVal]` assignment.

```
code[word][wordVal] = input[curVal];
// add
code[word][wordVal  + 1] = '\0';
```

To add it inside the `if(input[curVal + 1] == 32)` block risks it not being set should `curVal < length` become false before a space is encountered.

Answer (score 0):

When you copy words from `input` to `code`, you need to zero-terminate them (C strings are terminated by an extra zero byte):

```
code[word][wordVal] = input[curVal];
if (32 == input[curVal]) {
      // The character we just read was a space.
      // Transform it into a terminator.
      code[word][wordVal] = 0x0;
      wordVal = 0; // Prepare to write at first character...
      word++; // ...of next word.
 } else {
     wordVal++; // Next character
 }
 curVal++; // Next input byte
```

Then you also have to terminate the last word when you reach the end of the input.